# why is my tab separation not working?

Tags: python

I am trying to tab separate three variables as follows:

```
single_element = str(pos) + "\t" + str(ref) + "\t" +str(alt)
```

the output I get with `print(single_element)` is:

```
pos\tref\talt
```

but what I would like is:

```
pos    ref    alt
```

Comment: What if you `print(single_element)`?

Comment: sorry yes edited accordingly

Comment: This is probably because the your output device (IDE console) doesn't support tabs. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I've tried your code and work perfectly in Python 2.7. and 3.6 What is your Python version?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `expandtabs` to specify the tabstop

```
print(single_element.expandtabs(8))
```

Comment: You probably meant to write `print(single_element.expandtabs(8))`

Comment: Thank you @Leva7. `print(single_element).expandtabs(8)` gives the same result. But I modified my answer.

Comment: I don't know what kind of language are you using, but in Python 3 `print` returns `None`, so your call essentially turns into `None.expandtabs(8)`, which will obviously throw an exception.

Comment: Well, I am using `python version 2.7` . Both are working fine!